# Error while trying to install rgbdslam

Tags: ros, octomap, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to install rgbdslam using:-

```
$ rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg
```

I get an error msg as follows -

```
Unable to locate package ros-DISTRO-octomap-mapping
```

What can I do to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65591/error-while-trying-to-install-rgbdslam/) by [eskendertamrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/5193/eskendertamrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-20**:
Update your question to include your operating system, your ros distro, and what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why you get this error, but if you install the debian package manually it probably "solves" the problem. For fuerte execute

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping
```

For groovy:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-octomap-mapping
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eskendertamrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/5193/eskendertamrat/) on 2013-06-21**:
Thanks. I do install the octomap-mapping and it doesn't show that error anymore. But, it says Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query Missing resource. I try the mechanism of editing the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. But, it's not working. Any suggestions on that one?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-06-21**:
Look, we cannot guess the solution to an error based on the fact that an error occurs.  You need to post the particular messages you get to give people a chance at understanding what happens exactly.

**Comment by [eskendertamrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/5193/eskendertamrat/) on 2013-06-21**:
Okay. I'll be more specific from now on. It's just I'm new to Ubuntu and I really needed the solution at the time. It's fixed when I follow the " RGB-D SLAM for "Not-yet" ROS Users" instruction. Much thanks for your help, Felix.